# Problems with apache rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am running tomcat on centos6. I'm trying to configure Apache as a front end to tomcat so I could access:

```
help-test.example.com:8080/4-3/help
help-test.example.com:8080/4-2/help
help-test.example.com:8080/4-1/help
```

via:

```
help-test.example.com/4-3/help
help-test.example.com/4-2/help
help-test.example.com/4-1/help
```

with below apache configuration it is working:

```
VirtualHost *:443>
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

    ServerName help-test.example.com:443
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key


    ProxyPass        / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

     
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error-ssl.log
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access-ssl.log combined
     RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite-ssl.log"
     RewriteLogLevel 3
/VirtualHost>

VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  help-test.example.com
    Redirect / https://help-test.example.com
/VirtualHost>
```

but one more thing needs also to be done when I access :

```
help-test.example.com/help --> help-test.example.com/4-3/help
```

I have tried to add:

```
   RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/help/
    RewriteRule (.*) /4-3/help [L,NE,R]
```

getting an error:
This web page has a redirect loop

```
192.168.1.40 - - [26/Mar/2015:10:13:26 +0000] [help-test.example.com/sid#7f89baa41700][rid#7f89bab202a8/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /4-3/help
192.168.1.40 - - [26/Mar/2015:10:13:26 +0000] [help-test.example.com/sid#7f89baa41700][rid#7f89bab202a8/initial] (3) applying pattern '(help)' to uri '/4-3/help'
192.168.1.40 - - [26/Mar/2015:10:13:26 +0000] [help-test.example.com/sid#7f89baa41700][rid#7f89bab202a8/initial] (2) rewrite '/4-3/help' -> '/4-3/help'
192.168.1.40 - - [26/Mar/2015:10:13:26 +0000] [help-test.example.com/sid#7f89baa41700][rid#7f89bab202a8/initial] (2) explicitly forcing redirect with https://help-test.example.com/4-3/help
192.168.1.40 - - [26/Mar/2015:10:13:26 +0000] [help-test.example.com/sid#7f89baa41700][rid#7f89bab202a8/initial] (1) redirect to https://help-test.example.com/4-3/help [REDIRECT/302]
192.168.1.40 - - [26/Mar/2015:10:13:26 +0000] [help-test.example.com/sid#7f89baa41700][rid#7f89bab0c308/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /4-3/help
192.168.1.40 - - [26/Mar/2015:10:13:26 +0000] [help-test.example.com/sid#7f89baa41700][rid#7f89bab0c308/initial] (3) applying pattern '(help)' to uri '/4-3/help'
192.168.1.40 - - [26/Mar/2015:10:13:26 +0000] [help-test.example.com/sid#7f89baa41700][rid#7f89bab0c308/initial] (2) rewrite '/4-3/help' -> '/4-3/help'
192.168.1.40 - - [26/Mar/2015:10:13:26 +0000] [help-test.example.com/sid#7f89baa41700][rid#7f89bab0c308/initial] (2) explicitly forcing redirect with https://help-test.example.com/4-3/help
192.168.1.40 - - [26/Mar/2015:10:13:26 +0000] [help-test.example.com/sid#7f89baa41700][rid#7f89bab0c308/initial] (1) redirect to https://help-test.example.com/4-3/help [REDIRECT/302]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/help/
RewriteRule (.*) /4-3/help [L,NE,R]
```

You are getting a redirect loop here because you are saying that if the URL is *not* `/help/` then redirect to `/4-3/help` (etc, etc, ...). You need to reverse the logic and only redirect when it *is* `/help/`.

Change to...

```
RewriteRule ^/?help$ /4-3/help [R,L]
```

NB: This is a temporary (302) redirect. Change `R` to `R=301` to make it permanent.

**EDIT:** There appeared to be *something* that was appending a trailing slash to the request before the rewrite was processed, so the `RewriteRule` pattern needed to be changed to `^/help/$` (the `?` was omitted since the directive is being applied directly in the server config).

Comment: thanks w3d. it is almost working. I can access now using:

help-test.example.com/help/help

but how to shrink it to:

help-test.example.com/help

thanks

Comment: Where exactly are you placing these directives?

Comment: just below SSL configuration before Proxypass

Comment: When it does redirect, does it redirect to `/4-3/help` or `/help/4-3/help`? You aren't setting the `DocumentRoot` in your VirtualHost - what is the document root?

Comment: when i try to access `help-test.example.com/help` I can see in logs:
`init rewrite engine with requested uri /help/
/applying pattern '(^/?help$)' to uri '/help/'
pass through /help/`  and can see a webpage

and getting error because I think it is on 4-3 level

but when i try to access `help-test.example.com/help/help` I'm getting page:
`applying pattern '(^/?help$)' to uri '/help/faces/helppages/main.jspx'
initial] (1) pass through /help/faces/helppages/main.jspx`

Comment: Is your system implicitly appending a slash to the URL (however, I don't quite understand the 2nd example)? Try changing the pattern from `/?help$` to `/help/`.

Comment: changing to `RewriteRule ^/help/ /4-3/$0 [R=301,L]` worked. thanks a lot